# Spring Framework validate request parameter or path variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know I can validate forms in Spring, but can I apply similar validate to URL parameters? For example, I have a method in my controller as follows:

```
public String edit(@PathVariable("system") String system, 
    @RequestParam(value="group") String group,
    ModelMap model) throws DAOException {
```

Can I validate the values of `system` and `group` before the method is called, to ensure they are of a certain value or match a certain regex?

Thanks

Comment: Don't have time to provide a full answer, so just a comment: you can't do it with JSR-303, until they add the method extension, but you can do it with AOP.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use Spring Asserts for this. The Assert api (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html) runs a supplied expression against the specified parameters and if the expression equates to false then it throws an exception.

Ex:
Assert.isTrue(system.equals("ValidSystemName"), "You must supply a valid system");

It also contains functions to check that parameters are not null or are not empty strings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an annotation that marks parameters that should be validated. This annotation needs a `@Retention` of `RUNTIME` and a `@Target` of `ElementType.PARAMETER`.
- Create a validator implemented as an AspectJ Aspect.
- Wrap calls to controllers with this validator.

A sample annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Documented
public @interface ValidSystemParameter {
}
```

A sample validator:

```
@Aspect
public class ValidSystemParameterValidator {
    @Pointcut("TODO: write your pointcut expression")
    public void controllerMethodWithValidSystemParameter();

    @Before(pointcut = "controllerMethodWithValidSystemParameter()")
    public void validateSystemParameter(String systemParameter) {
        // validate the parameter (throwing an exception)
    }
}
```

To learn about the AspectJ pointcut expression language see: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html

To learn about AspectJ integration in Spring see: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late, but with Spring 3.0 you have the option of using JSR-303 validation with the `@Valid` annotation. There are also some more specific annotations as `@DateTimeFormat` and `@NumberFormat`. More details here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/validation.html#validation-mvc
As I see it you have two options:

- Define your request parameters as objects and user JSR-303
  validation.
- Use the Assert api as mentioned above.

If you just want to make a simple validation on a single value, I would go with the latter (that's what I did when I had simple int values to check for max value).